# Car purchase upon arrival in US

Tags: usa, driving-license, car, social-security

We are arriving in Los Angeles, holidaying for 6 days and then planning on driving to New Orleans over a few days. what challenges will we face doing this given we won't have an international driver's licence, Social Security Number or credit history. We will pay via money transfer so no loan required. Any help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Would it be easier to lease to start?

Comment: Credit history should not matter since you're planning to pay for the car outright. It *would* matter for a lease, of course, so the answer to your question is probably "no."  (It has been decades since I bought a car, but I don't remember giving my social security number.)

Comment: When we arrived in California we attempted to purchase a car, were told by the DMV that we could with our New Zealand license, but then when we went to register the car they told us we had to have CA residence.  They would not allow us to just use our friend's address.  It's possible that if we'd just given that address to start with it may not have been a problem, but we had already told them we didn't live in CA.  Our friend owns the car instead

Comment: @Midavalo for purchasers who intend to export a vehicle to another state, there's usually a provision for a temporary registration.  I suppose an in-state residence is not required for such a registration.

Comment: I see a ["One trip permit"](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/brochures/fast_facts/ffvr36) but I don't know if it would apply and you couldn't use the car in LA for touring. Somehow you'd need to get insurance too.